# Any thoughs on crashes like this with fiware-orion on CoreOS + Docker?

Tags: fiware-orion

Context Broker Orion crashes in my Cloud + CoreOS + Docker architecture, by using a centos6 based dockerfile definition and the latest rpm compilation provided.

Any thoughts on crashes like the one I paste here? After 20/30 ContextUpdates it stops. Actually, cygnus and proton are subscribed.

```
DEBUG@11:34:05  httpRequestSend.cpp[409]: Sending message 114 to HTTP server: sending message of 649 bytes to HTTP server
INFO@11:34:05  MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[960]: Database Operation Successful (update: { $set: { lastNotification: 1434022445 }, $inc: { count: 1 } }, query: { _id: ObjectId('55795ab89b16d6c37d911b90') })
DEBUG@11:34:05  MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[925]: blocked due to throttling, current time is:
DEBUG@11:34:05  MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1941]: Docs found: 1
DEBUG@11:34:05  sem.cpp[255]: mongoUpdateContext gives the 'req' semaphore for 'ngsi10 update request'
DEBUG@11:34:05  restReply.cpp[67]: Response 95: responding with 734 bytes, Status Code 200
DEBUG@11:34:05  restReply.cpp[68]: Response payload: '{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "Node",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "TimeInstant",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "batteryCharge",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "rows",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "columns",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
'
DEBUG@11:34:05  UpdateContextResponse.cpp[74]: destroyed
DEBUG@11:34:05  RegisterContextResponse.cpp[56]: destroyed
INFO@11:34:05  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@11:34:05  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to node-2:5050/notify
INFO@11:34:05  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
*** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: /usr/bin/contextBroker terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ff44c9e4527]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x1024b9)[0x7ff44c9e44b9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__longjmp_chk+0x33)[0x7ff44c9e4423]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0xee55)[0x7ff44df5be55]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x326a0)[0x7ff44c9146a0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(nanosleep+0x2d)[0x7ff44c98ea3d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(sleep+0xe0)[0x7ff44c98e8b0]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(main+0x90a)[0x49e5da]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7ff44c900d5d]
/usr/bin/contextBroker[0x483219]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00737000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107197                            /usr/bin/contextBroker
00937000-00941000 rw-p 00337000 08:09 2107197                            /usr/bin/contextBroker
00941000-00989000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
018c0000-01923000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ff428000000-7ff428029000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff428029000-7ff42c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff42f7ff000-7ff42f800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff42f800000-7ff430000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff430000000-7ff430021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff430021000-7ff434000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff434000000-7ff434029000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff434029000-7ff438000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff438000000-7ff440000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff440000000-7ff440021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff440021000-7ff444000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff444418000-7ff444419000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff444419000-7ff444c19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff444c19000-7ff444c1a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff444c1a000-7ff44541a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44541a000-7ff44541b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44541b000-7ff445c1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:20]
7ff445c1b000-7ff445c1c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff445c1c000-7ff44641c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:19]
7ff44641c000-7ff446421000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5529                       /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7ff446421000-7ff446620000 ---p 00005000 08:09 5529                       /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7ff446620000-7ff446621000 r--p 00004000 08:09 5529                       /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7ff446621000-7ff446622000 rw-p 00005000 08:09 5529                       /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7ff446622000-7ff44662e000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5531                       /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7ff44662e000-7ff44682e000 ---p 0000c000 08:09 5531                       /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7ff44682e000-7ff44682f000 r--p 0000c000 08:09 5531                       /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7ff44682f000-7ff446830000 rw-p 0000d000 08:09 5531                       /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7ff446830000-7ff446832000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5455                       /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7ff446832000-7ff446a31000 ---p 00002000 08:09 5455                       /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7ff446a31000-7ff446a32000 r--p 00001000 08:09 5455                       /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7ff446a32000-7ff446a33000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 5455                       /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7ff446a33000-7ff446a50000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5560                       /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7ff446a50000-7ff446c4f000 ---p 0001d000 08:09 5560                       /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7ff446c4f000-7ff446c50000 r--p 0001c000 08:09 5560                       /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7ff446c50000-7ff446c51000 rw-p 0001d000 08:09 5560                       /lib64/libselinux.so.1
7ff446c51000-7ff446c52000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff446c52000-7ff446c59000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5445                       /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7ff446c59000-7ff446e59000 ---p 00007000 08:09 5445                       /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7ff446e59000-7ff446e5a000 r--p 00007000 08:09 5445                       /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7ff446e5a000-7ff446e5b000 rw-p 00008000 08:09 5445                       /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7ff446e5b000-7ff446e89000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff446e89000-7ff447dce000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107212                    /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
7ff447dce000-7ff447fcd000 ---p 00f45000 08:09 2107212                    /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
7ff447fcd000-7ff447fce000 rw-p 00f44000 08:09 2107212                    /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
7ff447fce000-7ff447fde000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6734                       /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.1.6
7ff447fde000-7ff4481dd000 ---p 00010000 08:09 6734                       /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.1.6
7ff4481dd000-7ff4481de000 rw-p 0000f000 08:09 6734                       /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.1.6
7ff4481de000-7ff448397000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6626                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7ff448397000-7ff448596000 ---p 001b9000 08:09 6626                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7ff448596000-7ff4485b1000 r--p 001b8000 08:09 6626                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7ff4485b1000-7ff4485bd000 rw-p 001d3000 08:09 6626                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7ff4485bd000-7ff4485c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff4485c1000-7ff448623000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6728                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7ff448623000-7ff448822000 ---p 00062000 08:09 6728                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7ff448822000-7ff448826000 r--p 00061000 08:09 6728                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7ff448826000-7ff44882d000 rw-p 00065000 08:09 6728                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7ff44882d000-7ff44882f000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5499                       /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
7ff44882f000-7ff448a2e000 ---p 00002000 08:09 5499                       /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
7ff448a2e000-7ff448a2f000 r--p 00001000 08:09 5499                       /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
7ff448a2f000-7ff448a30000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 5499                       /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
7ff448a30000-7ff448a3a000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5503                       /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7ff448a3a000-7ff448c39000 ---p 0000a000 08:09 5503                       /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7ff448c39000-7ff448c3a000 r--p 00009000 08:09 5503                       /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7ff448c3a000-7ff448c3b000 rw-p 0000a000 08:09 5503                       /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7ff448c3b000-7ff448c54000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6720                       /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7ff448c54000-7ff448e53000 ---p 00019000 08:09 6720                       /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7ff448e53000-7ff448e54000 r--p 00018000 08:09 6720                       /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7ff448e54000-7ff448e55000 rw-p 00019000 08:09 6720                       /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
7ff448e55000-7ff448e6b000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5556                       /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7ff448e6b000-7ff44906b000 ---p 00016000 08:09 5556                       /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7ff44906b000-7ff44906c000 r--p 00016000 08:09 5556                       /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7ff44906c000-7ff44906d000 rw-p 00017000 08:09 5556                       /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7ff44906d000-7ff44906f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44906f000-7ff44907d000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5505                       /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44907d000-7ff44927c000 ---p 0000e000 08:09 5505                       /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44927c000-7ff44927d000 r--p 0000d000 08:09 5505                       /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44927d000-7ff44927e000 rw-p 0000e000 08:09 5505                       /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44927e000-7ff449406000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107220                    /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
7ff449406000-7ff449606000 ---p 00188000 08:09 2107220                    /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
7ff449606000-7ff449613000 rw-p 00188000 08:09 2107220                    /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
7ff449613000-7ff449614000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff449614000-7ff449753000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107200                    /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
7ff449753000-7ff449953000 ---p 0013f000 08:09 2107200                    /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
7ff449953000-7ff449964000 rw-p 0013f000 08:09 2107200                    /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
7ff449964000-7ff449966000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff449966000-7ff449969000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5471                       /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.5.0
7ff449969000-7ff449b68000 ---p 00003000 08:09 5471                       /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.5.0
7ff449b68000-7ff449b69000 r--p 00002000 08:09 5471                       /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.5.0
7ff449b69000-7ff449b6a000 rw-p 00003000 08:09 5471                       /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.5.0
7ff449b6a000-7ff449bdc000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5461                       /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
7ff449bdc000-7ff449ddb000 ---p 00072000 08:09 5461                       /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
7ff449ddb000-7ff449ddc000 r--p 00071000 08:09 5461                       /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
7ff449ddc000-7ff449ddf000 rw-p 00072000 08:09 5461                       /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
7ff449ddf000-7ff449e7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107217                    /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.26.14.12
7ff449e7b000-7ff44a07b000 ---p 0009c000 08:09 2107217                    /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.26.14.12
7ff44a07b000-7ff44a082000 rw-p 0009c000 08:09 2107217                    /usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.26.14.12
7ff44a082000-7ff44a0a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6727                       /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
7ff44a0a9000-7ff44a2a8000 ---p 00027000 08:09 6727                       /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
7ff44a2a8000-7ff44a2aa000 rw-p 00026000 08:09 6727                       /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
7ff44a2aa000-7ff44a2ac000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5450                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7ff44a2ac000-7ff44a4ac000 ---p 00002000 08:09 5450                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7ff44a4ac000-7ff44a4ad000 r--p 00002000 08:09 5450                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7ff44a4ad000-7ff44a4ae000 rw-p 00003000 08:09 5450                       /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7ff44a4ae000-7ff44a4e7000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5526                       /lib64/libnspr4.so
7ff44a4e7000-7ff44a6e7000 ---p 00039000 08:09 5526                       /lib64/libnspr4.so
7ff44a6e7000-7ff44a6e8000 r--p 00039000 08:09 5526                       /lib64/libnspr4.so
7ff44a6e8000-7ff44a6ea000 rw-p 0003a000 08:09 5526                       /lib64/libnspr4.so
7ff44a6ea000-7ff44a6ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44a6ec000-7ff44a6f0000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5547                       /lib64/libplc4.so
7ff44a6f0000-7ff44a8ef000 ---p 00004000 08:09 5547                       /lib64/libplc4.so
7ff44a8ef000-7ff44a8f0000 r--p 00003000 08:09 5547                       /lib64/libplc4.so
7ff44a8f0000-7ff44a8f1000 rw-p 00004000 08:09 5547                       /lib64/libplc4.so
7ff44a8f1000-7ff44a8f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5548                       /lib64/libplds4.so
7ff44a8f4000-7ff44aaf3000 ---p 00003000 08:09 5548                       /lib64/libplds4.so
7ff44aaf3000-7ff44aaf4000 r--p 00002000 08:09 5548                       /lib64/libplds4.so
7ff44aaf4000-7ff44aaf5000 rw-p 00003000 08:09 5548                       /lib64/libplds4.so
7ff44aaf5000-7ff44ab1a000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6697                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7ff44ab1a000-7ff44ad1a000 ---p 00025000 08:09 6697                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7ff44ad1a000-7ff44ad20000 r--p 00025000 08:09 6697                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7ff44ad20000-7ff44ad21000 rw-p 0002b000 08:09 6697                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7ff44ad21000-7ff44ae58000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6691                       /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7ff44ae58000-7ff44b057000 ---p 00137000 08:09 6691                       /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7ff44b057000-7ff44b05c000 r--p 00136000 08:09 6691                       /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7ff44b05c000-7ff44b05e000 rw-p 0013b000 08:09 6691                       /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7ff44b05e000-7ff44b060000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44b060000-7ff44b088000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6721                       /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7ff44b088000-7ff44b287000 ---p 00028000 08:09 6721                       /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7ff44b287000-7ff44b28b000 r--p 00027000 08:09 6721                       /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7ff44b28b000-7ff44b28c000 rw-p 0002b000 08:09 6721                       /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7ff44b28c000-7ff44b2c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6730                       /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7ff44b2c7000-7ff44b4c6000 ---p 0003b000 08:09 6730                       /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7ff44b4c6000-7ff44b4c9000 r--p 0003a000 08:09 6730                       /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7ff44b4c9000-7ff44b4ca000 rw-p 0003d000 08:09 6730                       /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7ff44b4ca000-7ff44b4cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44b4cb000-7ff44b4e0000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5576                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7ff44b4e0000-7ff44b6df000 ---p 00015000 08:09 5576                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7ff44b6df000-7ff44b6e0000 r--p 00014000 08:09 5576                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7ff44b6e0000-7ff44b6e1000 rw-p 00015000 08:09 5576                       /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7ff44b6e1000-7ff44b6e4000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5444                       /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7ff44b6e4000-7ff44b8e3000 ---p 00003000 08:09 5444                       /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7ff44b8e3000-7ff44b8e4000 r--p 00002000 08:09 5444                       /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7ff44b8e4000-7ff44b8e5000 rw-p 00003000 08:09 5444                       /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7ff44b8e5000-7ff44b90e000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5497                       /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7ff44b90e000-7ff44bb0e000 ---p 00029000 08:09 5497                       /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7ff44bb0e000-7ff44bb0f000 r--p 00029000 08:09 5497                       /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7ff44bb0f000-7ff44bb10000 rw-p 0002a000 08:09 5497                       /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7ff44bb10000-7ff44bb11000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44bb11000-7ff44bbec000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5501                       /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7ff44bbec000-7ff44bdeb000 ---p 000db000 08:09 5501                       /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7ff44bdeb000-7ff44bdf5000 r--p 000da000 08:09 5501                       /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7ff44bdf5000-7ff44bdf7000 rw-p 000e4000 08:09 5501                       /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7ff44bdf7000-7ff44be38000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5473                       /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7ff44be38000-7ff44c038000 ---p 00041000 08:09 5473                       /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7ff44c038000-7ff44c039000 r--p 00041000 08:09 5473                       /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7ff44c039000-7ff44c03b000 rw-p 00042000 08:09 5473                       /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7ff44c03b000-7ff44c088000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5507                       /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44c088000-7ff44c287000 ---p 0004d000 08:09 5507                       /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44c287000-7ff44c289000 r--p 0004c000 08:09 5507                       /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44c289000-7ff44c28b000 rw-p 0004e000 08:09 5507                       /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.2
7ff44c28b000-7ff44c2bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5479                       /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
7ff44c2bd000-7ff44c4bc000 ---p 00032000 08:09 5479                       /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
7ff44c4bc000-7ff44c4bd000 rw-p 00031000 08:09 5479                       /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
7ff44c4bd000-7ff44c4d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5552                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7ff44c4d4000-7ff44c6d4000 ---p 00017000 08:09 5552                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7ff44c6d4000-7ff44c6d5000 r--p 00017000 08:09 5552                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7ff44c6d5000-7ff44c6d6000 rw-p 00018000 08:09 5552                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7ff44c6d6000-7ff44c6da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44c6da000-7ff44c6e1000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5558                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
7ff44c6e1000-7ff44c8e0000 ---p 00007000 08:09 5558        consumer               /lib64/librt-2.12.so
7ff44c8e0000-7ff44c8e1000 r--p 00006000 08:09 5558                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
7ff44c8e1000-7ff44c8e2000 rw-p 00007000 08:09 5558                       /lib64/librt-2.12.so
7ff44c8e2000-7ff44ca6c000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5437                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7ff44ca6c000-7ff44cc6c000 ---p 0018a000 08:09 5437                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7ff44cc6c000-7ff44cc70000 r--p 0018a000 08:09 5437                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7ff44cc70000-7ff44cc71000 rw-p 0018e000 08:09 5437                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7ff44cc71000-7ff44cc76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44cc76000-7ff44cc8c000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5458                       /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7ff44cc8c000-7ff44ce8b000 ---p 00016000 08:09 5458                       /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7ff44ce8b000-7ff44ce8c000 rw-p 00015000 08:09 5458                       /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7ff44ce8c000-7ff44cf0f000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5512                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7ff44cf0f000-7ff44d10e000 ---p 00083000 08:09 5512                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7ff44d10e000-7ff44d10f000 r--p 00082000 08:09 5512                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7ff44d10f000-7ff44d110000 rw-p 00083000 08:09 5512                       /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7ff44d110000-7ff44d1f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6732                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7ff44d1f8000-7ff44d3f8000 ---p 000e8000 08:09 6732                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7ff44d3f8000-7ff44d3ff000 r--p 000e8000 08:09 6732                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7ff44d3ff000-7ff44d401000 rw-p 000ef000 08:09 6732                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7ff44d401000-7ff44d416000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44d416000-7ff44d504000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107203                    /usr/lib64/libboost_regex-mt.so.5
7ff44d504000-7ff44d703000 ---p 000ee000 08:09 2107203                    /usr/lib64/libboost_regex-mt.so.5
7ff44d703000-7ff44d70a000 rw-p 000ed000 08:09 2107203                    /usr/lib64/libboost_regex-mt.so.5
7ff44d70a000-7ff44d70d000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107218                    /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
7ff44d70d000-7ff44d90c000 ---p 00003000 08:09 2107218                    /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
7ff44d90c000-7ff44d90d000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 2107218                    /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
7ff44d90d000-7ff44d921000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107225                    /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
7ff44d921000-7ff44db21000 ---p 00014000 08:09 2107225                    /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
7ff44db21000-7ff44db22000 rw-p 00014000 08:09 2107225                    /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
7ff44db22000-7ff44db35000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107211                    /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
7ff44db35000-7ff44dd35000 ---p 00013000 08:09 2107211                    /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
7ff44dd35000-7ff44dd37000 rw-p 00013000 08:09 2107211                    /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
7ff44dd37000-7ff44dd4d000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 2107214                    /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.22.0
7ff44dd4d000-7ff44df4c000 ---p 00016000 08:09 2107214                    /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.22.0
7ff44df4c000-7ff44df4d000 rw-p 00015000 08:09 2107214                    /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.22.0
7ff44df4d000-7ff44df9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 6629                       /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
7ff44df9f000-7ff44e19e000 ---p 00052000 08:09 6629                       /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
7ff44e19e000-7ff44e1a1000 rw-p 00051000 08:09 6629                       /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
7ff44e1a1000-7ff44e1c1000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 5418                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7ff44e396000-7ff44e3bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44e3bd000-7ff44e3c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff44e3c0000-7ff44e3c1000 r--p 0001f000 08:09 5418                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7ff44e3c1000-7ff44e3c2000 rw-p 00020000 08:09 5418                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7ff44e3c2000-7ff44e3c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffe2a0c0000-7ffe2a0e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe2a1b8000-7ffe2a1ba000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe2a1ba000-7ffe2a1bc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
1 ContextElements
```

It seems that it does not crash without this subscriptions.

thanks!

I think that what made it crash was a ContextUpdate from CEP:Proton, or at least its relation with, which has Orion as consumer. It sent following XML on http://node-1:1026/v1/updateContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updateContextRequest>
   <contextElementList>
    <contextElement>
         <entityId type="Node" isPattern="false">
            <id>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</id>
         </entityId>
        <contextAttributeList>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>Latitud</name>
              <contextValue>0.0</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>EventId</name>
              <contextValue>afb3e832-6253-4816-ad31-62df35550e1b</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>Longitud</name>
              <contextValue>0.0</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>DetectionTime</name>
              <contextValue>2015-06-11T13:34:43.53000UTC</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>Cost</name>
              <contextValue>0.0</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>Certainty</name>
              <contextValue>1</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>Name</name>
              <contextValue>NodeContextUpdate</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>presence</name>
              <contextValue>0</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>illuminance</name>
              <contextValue>0.0</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>Duration</name>
              <contextValue>0</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
       <contextAttribute>
            <name>batteryCharge</name>
              <contextValue>67</contextValue>
         </contextAttribute>
      </contextAttributeList>
    </contextElement>
   </contextElementList>
   <updateAction>UPDATE</updateAction>
</updateContextRequest>
```

Removing Proton subscription, Orion remains stable.

The fact is that when I manually send it it works.

Comment: What kind of "reference" are you using in your subscriptions? A DNS name or the plain IP of the notification receiver?

Comment: a host name defined in /etc/hosts

Comment: Try to use directly IPs in the subscribeContext request and tell us if the problem continues, please. I have some idea of what can be happening, but I need to confirm that...

Comment: No domain names, neither /etc/hosts strings. With IPs, orion still alive after ten minutes running...

Comment: Up and running one hour with traffic, it seems you have found what made it crash, great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame" is related with [a bug recently discovered in Orion 0.22.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1016). We plan to solve that bug for Orion 0.23.0 but while the fix comes, the workaround is to use directly IP addresses in reference field at subscribeContext.

**EDIT**: the bug has been already fixed in the develop branch, so it will be available on next Orion version (i.e. 0.23.0).

Comment: Edit answer to specify in which Orion version the bug will be fixed.