# Orion goes down randomly when send entities

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have installed Orion in a new machine, from the yum package and installing mongodb following the instructions from the Administration guide.

Also, I have deployed an orion-instance from wirecloud, and also I updated my old Orion instance from 0.21 to 0.22.

In all cases Orion goes down randomly and I have no idea why. Version 0.21 worked perfectly, but now it's very unstable.

I installed a cron task that checks if Orion has PID dead, and start it again, but the problem is that sometimes I get my Orion instance down for 1 minute.

I send requests like this:

```
    (curl http://my.orion.instance.es:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Alert",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "myemail@dot.com",
            "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "alert-type",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "10020"
            },{
                "name": "message",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "Flooding"
            },{
                "name": "status",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "100"
            },{
                "name": "gateway",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "5"
            }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

And the response is:

```
    {
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "alert-type",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "message",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "status",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "gateway",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ],
                "id": "myemail@dot.com",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "type": "Alert"
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And in this moment, Orion goes down (also happens if I send an UPDATE or DELETE).

I have ngsi2cosmos running, and show these messages (maybe the problem is here):

```
INFO in requests_wrappers [/root/ngsi2cosmos/requests_wrappers.py:58]:
   --> PUT http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/yyyyy/xxx/myemail@dot.com-Alert-status-text.txt?op=create&user.name=yyyyy&data=true
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in requests_wrappers [/root/ngsi2cosmos/requests_wrappers.py:62]:
   <-- 500
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in requests_wrappers [/root/ngsi2cosmos/requests_wrappers.py:64]:
  <-- {"RemoteException":{"message":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create file\/user\/yyyy\/xxx\/myemail@dot.com-Alert-status-text.txt. Name node is in safe mode.","exception":"RemoteException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException"}}
```

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

```
echo 'db.csubs.count()' | mongo orion --quiet
> 176

echo 'db.registrations.count()' | mongo orion --quiet
> 0
```

Running contextBroker in foreground:

```
[root@orion-figlass ~]# service contextBroker stop
Stopping...
contextBroker (pid  5043) is running...
Stopping contextBroker...                                  [  OK  ]
[root@orion-figlass ~]#
[root@orion-figlass ~]# contextBroker -fg
INFO@19:47:48  contextBroker.cpp[1411]: Orion Context Broker is running
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  mongoConnectionPool.cpp[184]: Successful connection to database
INFO@19:47:48  contextBroker.cpp[1191]: Connected to mongo at localhost:orion
INFO@19:47:48  MongoGlobal.cpp[480]: Database Operation Successful ({ conditions.type: "ONTIMEINTERVAL" })
INFO@19:47:48  contextBroker.cpp[1499]: Startup completed
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 66.249.81.169:60928/version
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 66.249.93.161:48199/version
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 66.249.93.161:48199/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[827]: Bad Input (invalid mime-type in Accept http-header)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[836]: Bad Input (error in URI parameters)
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 66.249.81.161:37559/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[827]: Bad Input (invalid mime-type in Accept http-header)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[836]: Bad Input (error in URI parameters)
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:31  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/version
INFO@19:48:31  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:31  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:48:31  badRequest.cpp[52]: Bad Input (service '/favicon.ico' not found)
INFO@19:48:31  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:34  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/version
INFO@19:48:34  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:34  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:48:34  badRequest.cpp[52]: Bad Input (service '/favicon.ico' not found)
INFO@19:48:34  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:49:11  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:49:11  badRequest.cpp[52]: Bad Input (service '/favicon.ico' not found)
INFO@19:49:11  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:49:12  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/version
INFO@19:49:12  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:49:12  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:49:12  badRequest.cpp[52]: Bad Input (service '/favicon.ico' not found)
INFO@19:49:12  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:49:53  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 130.206.84.11:36938/ngsi10/subscribeContext
INFO@19:49:53  MongoGlobal.cpp[1095]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Alert" } ], _id.servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^$/, /^/.*/ ] } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } })
INFO@19:49:53  MongoGlobal.cpp[1095]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Alert" } ], _id.servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^$/, /^/.*/ ] } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } })
INFO@19:49:53  mongoSubscribeContext.cpp[147]: Database Operation Successful (insert { _id: ObjectId('559c2d6142b637df6db61746'), expiration: 1436309393, reference: "http://wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:00-1:22:51:01-1", servicePath: "/#", entities: [ { id: ".*", type: "Alert", isPattern: "true" } ], attrs: [], conditions: [ { type: "ONCHANGE", value: [ "alert-type", "status" ] } ], lastNotification: 1436298593, count: 1, format: "XML" })
INFO@19:49:53  httpRequestSend.cpp[191]: Starting transaction to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:00-1:22:51:01-1
INFO@19:49:53  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:49:53  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:00-1:22:51:01-1
INFO@19:49:53  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:50:08  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/version
INFO@19:50:08  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:50:08  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:50:08  badRequest.cpp[52]: Bad Input (service '/favicon.ico' not found)
INFO@19:50:08  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:50:26  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 130.206.84.11:36957/ngsi10/subscribeContext
INFO@19:50:26  MongoGlobal.cpp[1095]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Alert" } ], _id.servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^$/, /^/.*/ ] } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } })
INFO@19:50:26  MongoGlobal.cpp[1095]: Database Operation Successful ({ query: { $or: [ { _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Alert" } ], _id.servicePath: { $in: [ null, /^$/, /^/.*/ ] } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } })
INFO@19:50:26  httpRequestSend.cpp[191]: Starting transaction to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:34-1:22:51:34-1
INFO@19:50:26  mongoSubscribeContext.cpp[147]: Database Operation Successful (insert { _id: ObjectId('559c2d8242b637df6db61747'), expiration: 1436309426, reference: "http://wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:34-1:22:51:34-1", servicePath: "/#", entities: [ { id: ".*", type: "Alert", isPattern: "true" } ], attrs: [], conditions: [ { type: "ONCHANGE", value: [ "alert-type", "status" ] } ], lastNotification: 1436298626, count: 1, format: "XML" })
INFO@19:50:26  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:50:27  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:34-1:22:51:34-1
INFO@19:50:27  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
```

At this moment, orion goes down:

```
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 66.249.93.161:48199/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[827]: Bad Input (invalid mime-type in Accept http-header)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[836]: Bad Input (error in URI parameters)
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 66.249.81.161:37559/favicon.ico
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[347]: Bad Input (no valid 'Accept-format' found)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[827]: Bad Input (invalid mime-type in Accept http-header)
WARNING@19:48:28  rest.cpp[836]: Bad Input (error in URI parameters)
INFO@19:48:28  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@19:48:31  rest.cpp[781]: Starting transaction from 188.76.231.187:18019/version
INFO@19:48:31  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
```

Screenshot of /version where displays the uptime (before that, uptime was 5 days, but when I start using the mashup, something goes wrong and Orion goes down).

[image: Uptime orion /version]

**EDIT 2:**

Installed gdb, executed ulimit -c unlimited
running contextBroker -fg
Now the shell shows more detailed errors:

```
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[191]: Starting transaction to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/23:22:00-1:23:22:01-1
INFO@20:21:06  rest.cpp[384]: Transaction ended
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/22:51:34-1:22:51:34-1
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to wirecloud.ld.testbed.fi-ware.eu:3000/callbacks/23:22:00-1:23:22:01-1
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to api.wiim.es:80/api/v1/alert
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
*** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: contextBroker terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x3c5ab02527]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c5ab024b9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__longjmp_chk+0x33)[0x3c5ab02423]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4[0x3c5e20eb25]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c5aa326a0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(nanosleep+0x2d)[0x3c5aaaca3d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(sleep+0xe0)[0x3c5aaac8b0]
contextBroker(main+0x90a)[0x49e5da]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3c5aa1ed5d]
contextBroker[0x483219]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00737000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 26350                              /usr/bin/contextBroker
00937000-00941000 rw-p 00337000 fc:01 26350                              /usr/bin/contextBroker
00941000-00989000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
0120e000-01271000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
34e4a00000-34e4a12000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 53961                          /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.16.1
34e4a12000-34e4c12000 ---p 00012000 fc:01 53961                          /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.16.1
34e4c12000-34e4c13000 rw-p 00012000 fc:01 53961                          /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.16.1
3899200000-3899203000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 55423                          /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
3899203000-3899402000 ---p 00003000 fc:01 55423                          /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
3899402000-3899403000 rw-p 00002000 fc:01 55423                          /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
389aa00000-389aa14000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 55424                          /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
389aa14000-389ac14000 ---p 00014000 fc:01 55424                          /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
389ac14000-389ac15000 rw-p 00014000 fc:01 55424                          /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
3c5a600000-3c5a620000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 11913                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3c5a81f000-3c5a820000 r--p 0001f000 fc:01 11913                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3c5a820000-3c5a821000 rw-p 00020000 fc:01 11913                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3c5a821000-3c5a822000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5aa00000-3c5ab8a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ab8a000-3c5ad8a000 ---p 0018a000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ad8a000-3c5ad8e000 r--p 0018a000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ad8e000-3c5ad8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ad8f000-3c5ad94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5ae00000-3c5ae17000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5ae17000-3c5b017000 ---p 00017000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5b017000-3c5b018000 r--p 00017000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5b018000-3c5b019000 rw-p 00018000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5b019000-3c5b01d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5b200000-3c5b202000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b202000-3c5b402000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b402000-3c5b403000 r--p 00002000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b403000-3c5b404000 rw-p 00003000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b600000-3c5b683000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5b683000-3c5b882000 ---p 00083000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5b882000-3c5b883000 r--p 00082000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5b883000-3c5b884000 rw-p 00083000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5ba00000-3c5ba07000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5ba07000-3c5bc06000 ---p 00007000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5bc06000-3c5bc07000 r--p 00006000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5bc07000-3c5bc08000 rw-p 00007000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5be00000-3c5be15000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5be15000-3c5c014000 ---p 00015000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5c014000-3c5c015000 r--p 00014000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5c015000-3c5c016000 rw-p 00015000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5c200000-3c5c213000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 9703                           /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
3c5c213000-3c5c413000 ---p 00013000 fc:01 9703                           /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
3c5c413000-3c5c415000 rw-p 00013000 fc:01 9703                           /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
3c5c600000-3c5c61d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c61d000-3c5c81c000 ---p 0001d000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c81c000-3c5c81d000 r--p 0001c000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c81d000-3c5c81e000 rw-p 0001d000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c81e000-3c5c81f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5ca00000-3c5ca49000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5ca49000-3c5cc48000 ---p 00049000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5cc48000-3c5cc49000 r--p 00048000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5cc49000-3c5cc4b000 rw-p 00049000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5ce00000-3c5ce16000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5ce16000-3c5d016000 ---p 00016000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5d016000-3c5d017000 r--p 00016000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5d017000-3c5d018000 rw-p 00017000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5d018000-3c5d01a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5d200000-3c5d232000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32266                          /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
3c5d232000-3c5d431000 ---p 00032000 fc:01 32266                          /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
3c5d431000-3c5d432000 rw-p 00031000 fc:01 32266                          /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1Aborted (core dumped)
```

Second trace error (Orion has goes down twice in this period):

```
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[424]: Notification Successfully Sent to api.wiim.es:80/api/v1/alert
INFO@20:21:06  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Transaction ended
*** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: contextBroker terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x3c5ab02527]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c5ab024b9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__longjmp_chk+0x33)[0x3c5ab02423]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4[0x3c5e20eb25]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c5aa326a0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(nanosleep+0x2d)[0x3c5aaaca3d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(sleep+0xe0)[0x3c5aaac8b0]
contextBroker(main+0x90a)[0x49e5da]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3c5aa1ed5d]
contextBroker[0x483219]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00737000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 26350                              /usr/bin/contextBroker
00937000-00941000 rw-p 00337000 fc:01 26350                              /usr/bin/contextBroker
00941000-00989000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
0120e000-01271000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
34e4a00000-34e4a12000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 53961                          /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.16.1
34e4a12000-34e4c12000 ---p 00012000 fc:01 53961                          /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.16.1
34e4c12000-34e4c13000 rw-p 00012000 fc:01 53961                          /usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10.16.1
3899200000-3899203000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 55423                          /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
3899203000-3899402000 ---p 00003000 fc:01 55423                          /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
3899402000-3899403000 rw-p 00002000 fc:01 55423                          /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
389aa00000-389aa14000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 55424                          /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
389aa14000-389ac14000 ---p 00014000 fc:01 55424                          /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
389ac14000-389ac15000 rw-p 00014000 fc:01 55424                          /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
3c5a600000-3c5a620000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 11913                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3c5a81f000-3c5a820000 r--p 0001f000 fc:01 11913                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3c5a820000-3c5a821000 rw-p 00020000 fc:01 11913                          /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3c5a821000-3c5a822000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5aa00000-3c5ab8a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ab8a000-3c5ad8a000 ---p 0018a000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ad8a000-3c5ad8e000 r--p 0018a000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ad8e000-3c5ad8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fc:01 32217                          /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3c5ad8f000-3c5ad94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5ae00000-3c5ae17000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5ae17000-3c5b017000 ---p 00017000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5b017000-3c5b018000 r--p 00017000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5b018000-3c5b019000 rw-p 00018000 fc:01 32221                          /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3c5b019000-3c5b01d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5b200000-3c5b202000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b202000-3c5b402000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b402000-3c5b403000 r--p 00002000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b403000-3c5b404000 rw-p 00003000 fc:01 60370                          /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3c5b600000-3c5b683000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5b683000-3c5b882000 ---p 00083000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5b882000-3c5b883000 r--p 00082000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5b883000-3c5b884000 rw-p 00083000 fc:01 9690                           /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3c5ba00000-3c5ba07000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5ba07000-3c5bc06000 ---p 00007000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5bc06000-3c5bc07000 r--p 00006000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5bc07000-3c5bc08000 rw-p 00007000 fc:01 32222                          /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3c5be00000-3c5be15000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5be15000-3c5c014000 ---p 00015000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5c014000-3c5c015000 r--p 00014000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5c015000-3c5c016000 rw-p 00015000 fc:01 34600                          /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c5c200000-3c5c213000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 9703                           /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
3c5c213000-3c5c413000 ---p 00013000 fc:01 9703                           /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
3c5c413000-3c5c415000 rw-p 00013000 fc:01 9703                           /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
3c5c600000-3c5c61d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c61d000-3c5c81c000 ---p 0001d000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c81c000-3c5c81d000 r--p 0001c000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c81d000-3c5c81e000 rw-p 0001d000 fc:01 61643                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c5c81e000-3c5c81f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5ca00000-3c5ca49000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5ca49000-3c5cc48000 ---p 00049000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5cc48000-3c5cc49000 r--p 00048000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5cc49000-3c5cc4b000 rw-p 00049000 fc:01 61732                          /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
3c5ce00000-3c5ce16000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5ce16000-3c5d016000 ---p 00016000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5d016000-3c5d017000 r--p 00016000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5d017000-3c5d018000 rw-p 00017000 fc:01 61642                          /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3c5d018000-3c5d01a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3c5d200000-3c5d232000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 32266                          /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
3c5d232000-3c5d431000 ---p 00032000 fc:01 32266                          /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1
3c5d431000-3c5d432000 rw-p 00031000 fc:01 32266                          /lib64/libidn.so.11.6.1Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to add the following information: are you using subscripotions or registrations? Using `echo 'db.csubs.count()' | mongo orion --quiet` and echo 'db.registrations.count()' | mongo orion --quiet` will provide that information.

Comment: In addition, try to run Orion in foreground, as some times crash-error are logged in the standard/error output but not logged in the log file. In order to do so, take the command line used by Orion when running as service (you can get it using `ps ax | grep contextBroker`) then run `contextBroker -fg <rest of command line parameters>`. Please, add any information you get in the output in that way to your question post.

Comment: By the way, ngsi2cosmos is pretty obsolete. I strongly encoruage to upgrade to Cygnus as our support is focused in that component.

Comment: I have edit the question with more info as requested, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is [this issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1016) that has been already solved in the developed branch, also related with this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781537/any-thoughs-on-crashes-like-this-with-fiware-orion-on-coreos-docker/30941453#30941453). The fix will come with Orion 0.23.0 version.

As temporal workaround, you can use IPs instead of hostnames in `reference` field in subscriptions.